# sqlmembershipprovider working in VS2010 development server but not in IIS6

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

Membership.ValidateUser returns true in VS2010 but false in IIS6. What can it be?

Comment: applicationName attribute could be a potential reason:http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/04/22/Always-set-the-_2200_applicationName_2200_-property-when-configuring-ASP.NET-2.0-Membership-and-other-Providers.aspx .But as mentioned below it could be wrong database.

Answer (score 1):

To name a few

- Wrong database connected
- Wrong configuration file
- Wrong credential entered
- Wrong username entered

... hard to say without more info